# AWS + S3 - Linux downloads, powershell stalls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I've set up an S3 bucket.

From a Linux host, once I create a config and credentials file, I can do:

aws s3api get-object --bucket <mybucket> --key <myfile> /root/<myfile>

and myfile is downloaded from S3.

From a Windows host, I do this in Powershell:

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey <myaccesskey> SecretKey <mysecretkey> -StoreAs default

PS C:\Users\Administrator> read-s3object -bucketname <mybucket> -key <myfile> -file <myfile>

and I get:

Downloading <myfile> 0% and the shell hangs, eventually timing out with:

read-s3object : A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ read-s3object -bucketname <bucket> -key <file> ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...dS3ObjectCmdlet:ReadS3ObjectCmdlet) [Read-S3Object]
   , InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.ReadS3ObjectCmdleth

Any ideas? I'm using exactly the same credentials for both....

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is...... in order to connect to S3, you need to allow egress of 443 and 80 from your instances.